# When is the rank of $X'WX$ equal to rank of $X$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $\bf X$ be an $n\times p$ full rank matrix and $\bf W$ be an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix. When is ${\rm rank}(\bf X'WX)$ equal to ${\rm rank}(\bf X)$?

Comment: It sounds like the rank of $X$ is $p$, so then for example if $W,X$ commute and the rank of $W$ equals $p$.

Comment: The connection to multiple regression seems tenuous to me (although I can imagine contexts where this could come up). This looks rather like a pure math question. I'm voting to migrate this to the [math.SE] SE site.

Comment: Are the diagonal elements of $W$ positive or non-negative?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429082/is-bab-with-positive-definite-a-and-full-row-rankb-k-itself-of-rank?rq=1