Can we prove that ABA' is positive definite if B is positive definite and A is of full row rank
Suppose $A$ is a $r \times n$ matrix and $Rank(A) = r$, $B$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix and $rank(B) = n$.

Can we prove that $ABA'$ is positive definite?

If it is not positive definiteness, what are the requirements that $A$ needs to have to make $ABA'$ positive definite?

just check the definition $x' M x > 0$ for any $x\ne 0$

@Exodd I can show that ABA' is positive semi-definite. The following post has a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429082/is-bab-with-positive-definite-a-and-full-row-rankb-k-itself-of-rank?rq=1. But why we should look at $Mx = 0$?

Since $\mathrm{Rank}(A)=r$,  if $A^\prime x=0$, then $x=0$.

Please re-check the dimensions of $B$ and $ABA^T$.  The latter has rank $\leq r$ but $r\leq m$ so...
